# Which unix flavor is the standard amazon EC2 linux image based on?

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance where I have bash & php 5.3 scripts running together (install / copy done by bash, web app via php of course), I need to port these files to a classic dedicated server.

My goal is to choose the "closest OS" to the standard amazon EC2 linux distribution, you know to minimize the work done in order to get these scripts to work on the dedicated box.

So, **which unix flavor is the standard amazon EC2 linux image based on?**

I recall reading somewhere that amazon linux AMI is based on redhat but I'm can't find the link anymore, amazon doesn't say anything about this on their website, I tried to google it but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: if it's vanilla redhat, then there'd be a /etc/redhat-release file saying what the version is. `uname -a` would probably also have the distro's name embedded.

Comment: Thanks Marc B! `/etc/redhat-release` doesn't exist on my EC2 instance, `uname -a` returned this:   `Linux ip-11-22-33-444 3.4.43-43.43.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 6 18:04:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, any idea what does this mean?

Comment: they've done their own custom build. it MAY be based off a standard distro, but you'd have to dig deeper to find if there's any traces left of that one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is based on redhat, but at this point its taken its own path. While you can use redhat/centos repositories, you may from time to time, run into dependency conflicts.